# OpenStack heat stack template to create instance to boot from cinder volume

Tags: openstack, volume, heat, cinder

I am trying to create an instance to boot from cinder volume as root-disk (vda). Flavor is created/defined with 0 on root-disk.

Below heat template, it is clearly mentioned that boot_index = 0 is

**device_name:** specifies the name of the device. Standard format of disk name is supported, for example /dev/vda. When the boot_index is set to 0, this field is mandatory. When boot_index is set to -1, this field is optional. The chosen devices must match the disk_bus types.

**boot_index:** specifies the boot identifier. This value is mandatory, 0 is specifies a boot disk,  and -1 specifies a non-boot disk.

I am kepting getting this error "Block Device Mapping is Invalid: Boot sequence for the instance and image/block device mapping combination is not valid. (HTTP 400) (Request-ID: req-e31e0dd6-adc1-4f74-b073-84d850c1bd84)"

Can anyone share your views please? Thanks.
I even removed those -1 vdb/vdc and vdd non-bootable volumes and got same error. Thanks.
Andrew

I commented our vda since it complainted "volume cannot be assigned the same device name as the root device vda"

```
AVA-1:
type: OS::Nova::Server
properties:
  availability_zone: { get_param: availability_zone }
  name: { str_replace: { template: $prefix_$name, params: { $prefix: { get_param: prefix }, $name: {get_param: ava1_name}}}}
  image: { get_param: ava_image_name }
  flavor: { get_param: flavor }
  key_name: { get_param: ava_key_name }
  block_device_mapping_v2:
    - volume_id: { get_param: ava1_volume_id_rootdisk }
      boot_index: 0
      #device_name: vda
    - { boot_index: "-1", device_name: "vdb", volume_id: { get_param: ava1_volume_id_amu } }
    - { boot_index: "-1", device_name: "vdc", volume_id: { get_param: ava1_volume_id_vmu0 } }
    - { boot_index: "-1", device_name: "vdd", volume_id: { get_param: ava1_volume_id_vmu1 } }
```

Comment: boot_index is working properly, somewhere on other hot files had used vda as boot_index 0, when I put boot_index 1, it considers as next letter of the vdx. So this case, when i put boot_index 1 for root-disk (wrong still) but at least I don't see the error. my root-disk became /dev/vdb. not as I expected. Thanks.

Comment: just commented out the image line, then we can proceed with boot_index =0. It works.